# Is it possible use one loop ouput as an input for another loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, file-handling

I have a two lists as follows:

```
NumberandLetter1=['1 E\n', '2 K\n']
NumberandLetter2=['1 E,L,K\n', '2 K,L\n']
```

From the first List I try to make dictionary of NUMBERS:LETTERS and I didn't have any issue for making dictionary for list1:

```
NumberandLetter1=['1 E\n', '2 K\n'] ----> {'E': 1, 'K': 2}
```

But, For the second list I want to replace each comma by a respective number with newline and write it as new file with executed time:

```
NumberandLetter2=['1 E,L,K\n', '2 K,L\n'] ---> ['1 E\n1 L,\n1 K\n', '2 K,\n2 L\n']
executedTimeOutput.txt=['1 E\n1 L,\n1 K\n', '2 K,\n2 L\n']
```

Then , Use this executedTimeOutput.txt as input for next loop inroder to get dictionary as same like as NumberandLetter1(list1)

The point is:

case1 --> If single line has one number and one letter make a dictionary of it.

case 2 -> If single line has one numeber and many letter make each letter with a respective no as a new line.

What I have tried:

when I encountered case 2 -> I just replaced each comma by a number with a newline and write it as newfile with executedtime. Then used this newfile as a input to get ouput like case 1.

It didnt take the file as an input . could some tell me how to solve this or some different idea to get same results.

```
import os
import sys
import random
from itertools import groupby, combinations, chain
from time import gmtime, strftime

def main(NumberandLetter,current):

    Mutant_dict = {}
    res_key = ''

    fh = open(NumberandLetter, 'r').readlines()

    MutatedAll = open(current+"output.txt", "w")
    for i in fh:
        if "," not in i:
            res_key = str(filter(str.isalpha, i))
            Mutant_dict[res_key] = int(filter(str.isdigit, i))
        else:
            MutatedAll.write(i.replace(",", "\n" + i[0] + " "))

            fh1 = open(os.getcwd()+"/"+current+"output.txt", 'r').readlines()
            for i in fh1:
               res_key = str(filter(str.isalpha, i))
               Mutant_dict[res_key] = int(filter(str.isdigit, i))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1],strftime("%d%m%y_%H%M%S", gmtime()))
```

EXPECT OUTPUT:

```
NumberandLetter1=['1 E\n', '2 K\n'] ----> {'E': 1, 'K': 2}
NumberandLetter2=['1 E,L,K\n', '2 K,L\n'] ----> {'E': 1, 'L': 1, 'K':1, 'K':2, 'L':2}
```

As for now I am getting like this:

```
    NumberandLetter2=['1 E,L,K\n', '2 K,L\n'] ---->{'ELK': 1, 'KL': 2}
```

I did it very simple in else condition:

```
hi=[]
Mt={'ELK': 1, 'KL': 2}
for key,val in Mt.iteritems():
    for k in key:
        hi.append(k+'%d' % (val,))

OUTPUT=['E1', 'L1', 'K1', 'K2', 'L2']
```

Comment: Give me a suggestion on this :Mt={'ELK': 1, 'KL': 2}
for key,val in Mt.iteritems():
    for k in key:
        print k,val

Comment: `{'E': 1, 'L': 1, 'K':1, 'K':2, 'L':2}` is not a valid python dictionary. Duplicate keys!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating things with this additional writes to a file. You don't need that at all. You don't even need to distinguish between these cases, since case1 is a **special case** of case2. Have a look at this:

```
def process(iterator):
    result = {}
    for line in iterator:
        value, _, rest = line.strip().partition(' ')
        value = int(value)
        for subline in rest.split(','):
            result[subline] = value
    return result

with open('my_file.txt') as fo:
    Mutant_dict = process(fo)
```

Note that dictionaries can't have duplicates, so your expected output is impossible. But you can easily convert what I've written into for example a list of `(key, value)` pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your for-loop in the following way

```
for i in fh: 
    s = i.strip().split(" ")
    value = int(s[0])
    keys = s[1].split(",")
    for key in keys:
        Mutant_dict[key] = value
```

string.split() works wonder here.

However, the code still probably does not do what you want: dictionaries can only have unique keys, so you can't expect "{'E': 1, 'L': 1, 'K':1, 'K':2, 'L':2}" to happen as a dictionary at all.

You could use some alternative data structure to store the information, or maybe you want to calculate the sum of the numbers (to {'E': 1, 'L': 3, 'K':3}). Either way is possible. I just don't know which is your intention. Thus it's left as an exercise ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to convert a case2 input to a case1:

```
NumberandLetter2 = ['1 E,L,B,A,K\n', '2 K,L\n'] 

def convert_list(alist):
    for i_list, items in enumerate(alist):
        print(items)
        if "," in items:
            slices = items.split(",")
            no_id = slices[0][0]
            slices[0] += '\n'
            for i in range(1, len(slices)-1):
                slices[i] = no_id + ' ' + slices[i] + '\n'
            slices[-1] = no_id + ' ' + slices[-1]
            alist[i_list] = slices
    return [item for sublist in alist for item in sublist]

print(convert_list(NumberandLetter2)) #prints: ['1 E\n', '1 L\n', '1 B\n', '1 A\n', '1 K\n', '2 K\n', '2 L\n']
```

It simply takes a list and writes another one. Definitely not the most pythonic piece of code but should work.